# Different Color for Every Day in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: colors, google-apps-script, google-sheets

All I want to do is to format every other day in different color. For example;

```
01.01.2012 is Grey
01.01.2012 is Grey
01.01.2012 is Grey
02.01.2012 is White
02.01.2012 is White
03.01.2012 is Grey
03.01.2012 is Grey
04.01.2012 is White and so on...
```

My purpose is to make the date column easy to read.

Appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: Here is what I'm looking for: http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/28/add-zebra-lines-when-value-changes/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering, i just accomplished this with 7 of these in conditional formatting for each day "ddd" of the week.

```
 apply to cell range E:E
 =IF(TEXT(E3,"ddd")="Thu",1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, one more thing!  Blank cells are Saturday ("Sat") so to keep those from colorizing dont include blanks like this:  =IF(AND(TEXT(E3,"ddd")="Sat",E3 > 0),1)